# A question on derivative of a function from $\Bbb R \to\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose we have a curve parameterized by a continuously differentiable function $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^n$. Suppose $g(t_0)=x_0$ then why $D(g(t_0))$ is a tangent vector to the curve at $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another hint: There's a lemma on the limits of sequences that states that, if $x^{(m)}_{j}$ is the $j$th component of the $m$th term of a sequence $\left(x^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $x_{j}$ that of an element $x\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$, then the following are equivalent:
$$x^{(n)}\to x\text{ as }n\to\infty\text{ (in the Euclidean metric)}$$ and
$$\text{ for each }j, x_{j}^{(n)}\to x_{j}\text{ as }n\to\infty\text{ in the standard metric on }\mathbb{R}.$$

Then it's a matter of using the Newton quotient(s).

[NB: Again, I'd rather put this is a series of comments but I haven't unlocked them yet.]

Answer (score 0):

Let's write $g'(t)$ instead of $D\bigl(g(t)\bigr)$.  Being differentiable doesn't mean that a tangent line exists.
We call $g'(t)$ the velocity vector from which not in all cases a tangent is given.  In case $g'(t_0)=0$ there may be a tangent line in $t_0$ or not.

Consider the $C^{\omega}$-path $g\colon\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $g(t):=(t^2,t^3)$; $g$ doesn't possess a tangent line in $t=0$.

For $g(t):=\bigl(\cos(t^2),\sin(t^2)\bigr)$ we have $g'(0)=0$, but a tangent line at $0$ exists.

Otherwise a path may have a tangent without being differentiable; consider for this case $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $g(t):=t^{1/3}$ at $t=0$.

Comment: How do you define a tangent line? It is a well known fact (actually follows immediately from the definition of differential) that the image of differential is tangent to the image of the function itself. In your examples simply the image of differential is zero.